# Multiply each element of an array of an object by a scalar

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have an array of objects, each object containing some arrays too.

I wonder how can I access easily the values, for example, to multiply them by a constant.

Probably there is a need for `forEach()`, I tried to do it like this:

```js
myArray = [{
    income: [1, 2, 3],
    outcome: [2, 3]
  },
  {
    income: [1, 9, 8, 5],
    outcome: [1, 3, 7]
  },
  {
    income: [7, 2, 8],
    outcome: [2, 6, 10]
  },
];

const myValue = 2;
myArray.forEach(ob => ob.income = ob.income * myValue, ob.outcome = ob.outcome * myValue);
```

The expected result, in this case, should be:

```
myArray = [
  {income: [2, 4, 6], outcome: [4, 6]},
  {income: [2, 18, 16, 10], outcome: [2, 6, 14]},
  {income: [14, 4, 16], outcome: [4, 12, 20]},
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `forEach()` to iterate over all the objects and than use  `Array.map()` to get the desired result.

```js
let myArray = [
            {income: [1, 2, 3], outcome: [2, 3]},
            {income: [1, 9, 8, 5], outcome: [1, 3, 7]},
            {income: [7, 2, 8], outcome: [2, 6, 10]},
];

const multiplyBy = 2;

myArray.forEach((obj)=>{
  obj.income = obj.income.map((a)=> a*multiplyBy);
  obj.outcome = obj.outcome.map((a)=> a*multiplyBy);
});

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take all properties and map new properties for new objects.

```js
var array = [{ income: [1, 2, 3], outcome: [2, 3] }, { income: [1, 9, 8, 5], outcome: [1, 3, 7] }, { income: [7, 2, 8], outcome: [2, 6, 10] }],
    factor = 2,
    result = array.map(o => 
        Object.assign(...Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) =>
            ({ [k]: v.map(f => f * factor) }))));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Mutating the original array

```js
var array = [{ income: [1, 2, 3], outcome: [2, 3] }, { income: [1, 9, 8, 5], outcome: [1, 3, 7] }, { income: [7, 2, 8], outcome: [2, 6, 10] }],
    factor = 2;

array.forEach(o => 
    Object
        .entries(o)
        .forEach(([k, v]) => o[k] = v.map(f => f * factor))
);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```